# Spricht man das 'r' in 'stottern'?

Tags: pronunciation

Ist das 'r' hörbar bei dem Wort 'stottern'? Wenn nicht, warum und gibt es ein Regel für ähnliche Worte?

Answer (score 2):

Das "r" in "stottern" muss als "er" betrachtet werden, und damit ist es ein a-Schwa und ist daher als /r/ nicht hörbar. Es gibt unzählige Wörter, wie z.B. "Wörter", "labern", "Salzburger", wo die Buchstabenfolge "er" als a-Schwa ausgesprochen wird.

Wie es in den vielen deutschen Dialekten gehandhabt wird, kann ich nicht sagen. In meinem nativen Salzburger Dialekt ist es so, und wenn ich mich um Hochdeutsch bemühe, ist es auch so.

Answer (score 1):

Du musst beim R unterscheiden, ob es vor oder nach dem Vokal der Silbe steht. Steht es davor, ist es ein Konsonant, wie z.B. in den Wörtern *brechen*, *Krach*, oder *rufen*.

Steht das R hingegen hinter dem Vokal der Silbe, ist es selbst ein Vokal, und zwar das sogenannte Tiefschwa. Dieses wird wie ein kurzes, schwaches A ausgesprochen. Du findest es z.B. in den Wörtern *Uhr*, *normal*, *Firn*. Es fällt auch auf, dass dieses Tiefschwa mit dem Vokal davor einen Diphthong bildet

Eine Sonderstellung hat die Reduktionssilbe *-er*. In der Reduktionssilbe *-e* wird bereits das E sehr kurz und schwach ausgesprochen, als *Schwa* eben. Kommt ein R hinzu, werden beide zusammen als Tiefschwa ausgesprochen. Das E fällt also ganz weg.

Answer (score 0):

Über die normale Aussprache wurde schon alles gesagt. Aber wenn ich einen Satz mit dem Wort "labern" wiederhole, weil jemand "laben" verstanden hat, bemühe ich mich dann um eine exakte Aussprache, und dann ist das "r" absolut hörbar.